# wordpress contact or message pages

Tags: wordpress, message, contacts

I have an idea for my wordpress blog.

I want to have a page where my readers can send me messages, not by email. Sort of like a comment, but they shouldn't be listed on the blog itself. And, I don't want to read them in the comment field, but instead have a separate view for it.

I have a few ideas, but I need your guidance to find the best way.

- I make a special page, using
  the [php_exec](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/)
- I add a comment field to the page but make it store in some other place than usual comments do.
- I use an already existing plugin that I have totally missed.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is one good thing about wordpress, it's the number of plugins available that do almost anything you can imagine. You can check if [WATS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wats/) suits your needs, if it doesn't just google "wordpress ticket plugin".

Comment: I thought there should be something like this around.

I'll see if it works!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a plugin that can create a new post via a frontend form such as Advanced Custom Fields Pro - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/, or Gravity Forms - http://www.gravityforms.com/ to create a new page with a form on it that submits data to a custom post type.